# Checking regressors' combinations

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression

I have a data frame which contains 100 values for 6 regressors, x1-x6 and 100 values for independent variable, y. My goal is to estimate multiple linear regression of y on 2 regressors and to choose the model with the highest R squared. I need to check all possible combinations of x. For example, estimate models y on x1,x2; y on x1,x3; y on x2,x3 and so on.
How can I check all these possible combinations and then run all the regressions? Probably I need to somehow use the combn() function but I have no idea how to do this along with regression estimation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I will create a reproducible dataset, since you have posted none.

```
set.seed(1)    # make the results reproducible
n <- 100
X <- matrix(rnorm(6*n), ncol = 6)
y <- X %*% sample(6) + rnorm(n)

X <- as.data.frame(X)
names(X) <- paste0("x", 1:6)

data <- cbind(X, y)
head(data)
```

The following solves the problem in successive `*apply` loops.
It does in the following steps.

1. Get the regressors full names knowing only that they start with a `"x"`.
2. Create a matrix of all possible combinations two by two.
3. Run all regressions possible in the first `lapply` loop. The formula is put together with `paste` and then coerced to class `"formula"`.
4. Get the `summary`'s, where th value of R^2 is computed with another `lapply`.
5. This is it. Now these two lists have all the information needed an the standard subsetting operators, such as `'[['`, can extarct whatever we need.

   1. The R^2 are extracted first with `sapply` because they will form a *vector* of values.
   2. Extract the coefficients of the model with maximum R^2 and the model's summary.

So let's do it.

```
regress <- grep("^x", names(data), value = TRUE)

regress_mat <- combn(regress, 2)

lm_list <- apply(regress_mat, 2, function(reg){
  fmla <- paste("y", paste(reg, collapse = "+"), sep = "~")
  fmla <- as.formula(fmla)
  lm(fmla, data)
})

smry_list <- lapply(lm_list, summary)
rsq <- sapply(smry_list, '[[', "r.squared")

coef(lm_list[[which.max(rsq)]])
#(Intercept)          x3          x4 
# -0.1400852   5.0556334   5.7352798

smry_list[[which.max(rsq)]]

#Call:
#  lm(formula = fmla, data = data)
#
#Residuals:
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#-11.6529  -4.6230   0.1127   3.7821  11.9342 
#
#Coefficients:
#              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#  (Intercept)  -0.1401     0.5763  -0.243    0.808    
#  x3            5.0556     0.5626   8.987 2.07e-14 ***
#  x4            5.7353     0.5867   9.775 4.11e-16 ***
#  ---
#  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 5.754 on 97 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.6714,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.6646 
#F-statistic:  99.1 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```